# Custom Nodes template issue

Tags: python, blender

I replaced line 137 in Custom Nodes template by
`return context.space_data.tree_type == 'GeometryNodeTree'`
but the category and nodes do not shows up in Geometry Node editor menus.

Why ?

I expect the category and nodes to shows up in Geometry Node editor menus.